Should I patch or overlay subfloor to deal with movement?
Our kitchen floor is on a basement (wood beams in Ohio with temperature change). The vinyl tile is cracking in some places that there is movement on the subfloor from an older subfloor and movement with foot traffic. My original plan was to rip up flooring and replace subfloor in places of need. I am curious if it would be better to just overlay the tile and current subfloor with a fresh AdvanceTec waterproof 3/4 OSB subfloor to create a double layer of strength?

What does "subfloor from an older subfloor" mean? Please revise to be more clear about the current state of things.

It is pretty obvious that what you need to do is remove the tile and get to the subfloor. Replacing anything that is weak or damaged. Do Not try to go over the existing floor.
I do not like OSB for anything. (personal preference) For a kitchen, where water can be spilled, I absolutely would not use OSB, even waterproof.  I would use 3/4 plywood. There is the possibility that the whole subfloor need replacing. That I would do entirely in 3/4 plywood.  I know that there are those that say the OSB "specs out", but I believe plywood promotes a stiffer and stronger floor.

Advantech (what I assume the OP meant) is a pretty commonly used subfloor, even for kitchens.  It's supposed to be pretty waterproof.

@Huesmann, I don't doubt you.  Key word, "Supposed".   As I said, it's a personal preference.  I don't like any OSB, like I don't like any Thai food.  It's just stuff I would not use.   I honestly can't support that with anything other than my own feeling about the product.

The foundation has to be good for what's above it to be stable.
I'm no flooring master, but the above principle seems to apply. You mention:

movement on the subfloor from an older subfloor

So you already have two layers of squiffly subfloor, and they're upsetting the tile. This seems it would make a bad foundation for a new subfloor.
I'd deduce ripping everything out (perhaps in stages if need be) and starting over fresh with a new proper subfloor. Then the final floor would have a decent foundation to last a long time on. Consult with flooring specialists in your area on how to handle the:

wood beams in Ohio with temperature change

when choosing the correct subfloor. Or ask a new question about this side of the project.
